# Fighting Robots. my small first program. Python language

Tags: python

I have some dictionaries set up like tables, for example:

```
SpdPts0 = {'Init Bonus':0,'Dodge Bonus':0,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}
SpdPts1 = {'Init Bonus':2,'Dodge Bonus':5,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}
SpdPts2 = {'Init Bonus':4,'Dodge Bonus':5,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}

DefPts0 = {'Block':0,'Dodge':0,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':0}
DefPts1 = {'Block':5,'Dodge':5,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':0}
DefPts2 = {'Block':10,'Dodge':10,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':1}
```

And I have a class set up like this for example:

```
class Robot:
    def __init_(self,name):
        self.name =  name
        self.Dodge = 0
        self.PtsSpeed = 2
        self.PtsDefence = 2
```

The (.PtsSpeed, .PtsDefence) will be increased by a fucntion when the robot gains points to be distributed by the user.

How can I update the class attribute "self.Dodge" by referencing both .PtsSpeed, and .PtsDefence to sum The ('Dodge' and 'Dodge Bonus') keys from the variables above?
Or please show me a way that will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self,name,rob_type=None):
        self.name =  name
        self.PtsSpeed = 2
        self.PtsDefence = 2
        self.Dodge = self.dodge_cal(rob_type)

    def dodge_cal(self, value=None):
        if value:
            return value['Dodge']
        else:
            return self.PtsSpeed + self.PtsDefence

SpdPts0 = {'Init Bonus':0,'Dodge Bonus':0,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}
SpdPts1 = {'Init Bonus':2,'Dodge Bonus':5,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}
SpdPts2 = {'Init Bonus':4,'Dodge Bonus':5,'Crit %':0,'Finness Bonus':0}

DefPts0 = {'Block':0,'Dodge':0,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':0}
DefPts1 = {'Block':5,'Dodge':5,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':0}
DefPts2 = {'Block':10,'Dodge':10,'Absorb':0,'Deflect':0,'MaxDefProgs':1}

bob = Robot('bob',DefPts2)

print(bob.Dodge) #10

foo = Robot('foo')
print(foo.Dodge) #4
```

Create a function that calculates it based on what was passed in. This is one way of doing it. There's a lot of way of doing it. Here if `rob_type` isn't passed it it's calculated it by default by adding the object's `PtsSpeed + PtsDefence`. `rob_type` takes in the full dictionary and make sure it has the proper key `'Dodge'`. You can then in turn calculate a lot more stats by making little functions and since you are accepting the dictionary and storing it in `rob_type` it doesn't matter what you want to do.

I would combine your `SpdPts` with your `DefPts` or what not but once again this is super broad so it's up to how you want to implement. good luck.